# CDTV board rev 2.3 can OCS Denise be upgraded to ECS

Tags: hardware-mods, amiga-cdtv

I came across [this post](https://eab.abime.net/showthread.php?t=11288) from a user 18 years years ago, where he had some luck in upgrading chips on the board 2.3. is it possible? He says he was able to get 2MB chip ram and ECS Super Denise, can I just swap Angus, Denise and that's it?

> I opened my upgraded A500+ motherboard and inserted my ECS Super Denise and Fatter Agnus (a Mini Mega Chip) onto the CDTV motherboard without any problems. Booted her up, and lo and behold, full ECS and 2MB Chip Ram...

Comment: I can't speak to CDTV, so just making a comment. While I believe you could just swap OCS for ECS chips in general (IIRC it was mainly the Agnus and Denise chips that were improved), I seem to recall that the Fatter Agnus was not a drop-in chip replacement, but more of a mini-board with Fatter Agnus on it that would fit into the (Fat) Agnus socket. Again, memory is hazy but I think the upgraded Denise was pin and electrically compatible, but really required OS 2.1+ to be useful (e.g. Productivity mode).